# How to use Ajax for this Chat application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I want to use Ajax for my chat application instead of refreshing an Iframe every second for new messages. Someone told me to use webservices with ajax. What should I do with my code to use Ajax?

Here is the code which shows Iframe which is called every second and Iframe src has an aspx page which displays chat messages

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function refreshConversatio() {
             document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').src = 'frmMessageDisplay.aspx';

            }
     </script>
    <body>
    <div id="divMessageDisplayPage" style="height: 724px; ">
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderDisplayMessage" runat="server">
          <iframe id="iframeDisplayMessage" name="iframeDisplayMessage" width="76%" style="background-color:White;" height="95%" frameborder="0" src="frmMessageDisplay.aspx" 
    onload="document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').contentWindow.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight)">
          </iframe>
          </asp:PlaceHolder> 
      </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function () { refreshConversatio(); }, 1000)


        </script>
 </body>
```

This is the Aspx page which is called in Iframe and it has literal which displays messages

```
 <div id="divConversation"  style="width: 100%;">

        <asp:Literal ID="RecepientConversation"  runat="server"/>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at leveraging SignalR to accomplish the task. Patrick Fletcher has a pretty nice set of tutorials with examples for building a basic chat app.

Tutorial Link:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr

http://www.asp.net/signalr